# .Net Maui AppInfo.Current.VersionString

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I am calling `AppInfo.Current.VersionString` on a Maui project deployed on UWP.

I am always getting back 1.0.0.1 I have tried changing

```
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>2.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>2</ApplicationVersion>
```

inside of the relay.csproj and I have also tried changing

```
<assemblyIdentity version="1.3.0.0" name="Relay.WinUI.app"/>
```

inside of the app.manifest inside the WinUI platform folder.

But always returning 1.0.0.1, I have also tried VersionTracking.CurrentVersion and seeing the same thing.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5137

Comment: That issue is closed and I am still seeing the issue, and the bottom comment I am slightly confused with what they are trying to get me to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the steps below to change the maui project version on UWP.

First, Please find the `Package.appxmanifest` file in the `Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest` .

Second, Double click the file and you can see the options then choose the `Packaging`.

Last, you can see the view below and you can change the project version.

[image]

Here is the information about the [Package version numbering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/apps/publish/publish-your-app/package-version-numbering?pivots=store-installer-msix).

Answer (score 2):

I'm finding that a clean and rebuild after setting ApplicationDisplayVersion and ApplicationVersion will enable AppInfo.Current.VersionString to retrieve the information correctly

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous 2 answers, I've also found (especially on Windows) that I need to delete the bin and obj folders before it starts picking up the correct numbers. Well, let me clarify - I've found that without it I can get the correct numbers to display, but when I package the app it still has the old numbers, so I have to delete the bin and obj folders first if I want the package folder to have the right numbers too.

Comment: Is this an answer on its own, or more of a comment on the other answers?

Comment: Hi @Adriaan, well, it depends on whether the other answers work or not. :-) Sometimes a solution works, sometimes it doesn't. If someone tries cleaning and it works, great, but if that doesn't work then I would try deleting the bin and obj folders. Personally cleaning has never worked for me - might be an environmental thing? (as I said, this is for me on Windows) I've always had to delete the bin and obj folders, so this is an answer for anyone who runs into the same issues as me with it.

Comment: P.S. the OP states that they're getting 1.0.0.1 back - i.e. 4 digits, not 3 - which suggests to me they're on Windows (Android only returns 3 digits), even though they never specified.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try building after deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders previously generated?

`ApplicationDisplayVersion` and `ApplicationVersion` are the properties that need to be set.

Something like this:

```
dotnet publish -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64 -p:ApplicationDisplayVersion=1.2.3 -p:ApplicationVersion=4
```

Comment: note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].